# Running in the IDE fails when using FullDebugMode for FastMM

Tags: delphi, debugging, fastmm

I am trying to use `FullDebugMode`(fastmm4) to have a detailed report of memory leaks.

While I can get this work succesfully in a dummy application that creates and doesn't free a `TStringList` I cannot in another application.

In both projects the dpr is like this:

```
{$DEFINE FullDebugMode}
{$DEFINE LogMemoryLeakDetailToFile}
uses
  FastMM4,
```

And I enabled `FullDebugMode` in Fasttmm inc options file.

in the project options in both projects I set the following settings to True:

In compiling tab:

**Emit runtime type information

Use debug dcus**

In linknig tab:

**Debug information**

Those settings work ok for the dummy app, but for the real one just after linking i can see the IDE event log window populate, and after

*Module Load: SHLWAPI.dll. No debug info. Base Address etc...*

immediately the program resets (like if I did CTRL-F2)

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is probably something wrong with FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll which is needed for FullDebugMode (and loaded after SHLWAPI.dll). 
Do you have FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll in the same directory as your application? Is it the right version?

Comment: YES! My mistake, i put the dll in the dpr folder instead than in the bin (output) folder. Stupid mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I have a situation where my `Output directory` in project options was changed and the output executable is created elsewhere (not in the `Win32/Debug`).